# How can I throw die in Perl debugger?

Tags: perl

I want to debug my Perl code with die.

I wrote this code.

```
eval {
  print("foo");
  print("bar");
  print("fizz");
  print("buzz");
}

if ($@) {
  print("error");
}
```

*Of course this code is an abstracted sample.

I want to run "if" route in the debugger without any code changes.

I want to run "if" route of this code in the debugger.

Comment: According to [perl5db](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5db): *"The debugger localizes a saved copy of $@ inside the subroutine, which allows it to keep $@ safe until it DB::eval returns, at which point the previous value of $@ is restored."* Maybe this is a reason why you cannot throw die?

Comment: Well, you have to change it to at least fix the syntax error :)

Comment: The best I can see is to make that `eval` actually fail by setting variables suitably while stepping through it

Answer (score 0):

The debugger doesn't change what the program does. You can change the value of variables, but that's it.

Fortunately, the code in question is executed based on the value of `$@`. So you would set the value of `$@` to something true.

Comment: I wondered if that would work. Setting `$@` was ignored, so after setting it, the debugger simply restored the original value. Curious.

Comment: @briandfoy, Of course, cause the debugger evaluates code in an eval... I'll adjust